# Underscore, underscore.string not playing nice

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, underscore.js

I have a rails 4.1.x project which has the following `application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require turbolinks
//= require showdown
//= require underscore
//= require underscore.string/underscore.string
//= require selectize.js/js/selectize
//= require jquery-bootpag/jquery.bootpag
//= require react
//=require_tree ./helpers
//= require_tree ./react_mixins
//= require_tree ./react_components
//= require backbone
//= require aisis_writer
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_tree .
//= require twbs/bootstrap
//= require chosen/chosen.jquery.min
```

Everything loads fin. Now I can do - from the Underscore js library:

```
var moe = {name: 'moe'};
moe === _.identity(moe);
```

And It works, But if I do - from the Underscore.string library:

```
_.levenshtein('kitten', 'kittah')
```

And I get `undefined function`. I was reading: [this part of the readme](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#nodejs-installation) which stipulates how to use it with underscore but I dont know if I have to go that far with rails. I was also looking at [this part of the source code](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/blob/master/lib/underscore.string.js#L669) and it defines a `_s` or it integrates with underscore.

Considering underscore.string is loaded after underscore and all the regular underscore functions work - its safe to say it exists. So what's going on? Bot libraries have been loaded properly and their are no console errors aside from the `undefined function` when I try and use an underscore.string function.

Answer (score 2):

As the readme says, if you want to use the Underscore.string functions from the `_` object, [you must mix them in](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#string-functions). Add the following line before you attempt to use `_.levenshtein`:

```
_.mixin(_.string.exports());
```

Or you can call `_.str.levenshtein` instead.

Comment: doing `console.log(_.str)` gives me undefined. the network tab (chrome) shows underscore.string loaded before underscore, but as you can see the application.js shows the opposite.

Comment: Then I'd say that your `//= require underscore.string/underscore.string` line isn't loading your library. Do you have a directory in `app/assets/javascripts` called `underscore.string`? Does it contain a file `underscore.string.js`? If it's loading afterwards, it sounds like it's being loaded by the `require_tree .`.